# cPanel bandwidth stat update frequency

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, bandwidth

The bandwidth stat in cPanel updates two or three times a day. Is it my host's settings or where can I see real time bandwidth usage stat?

Comment: My host does the same. It's not possible to view the stats live through cpanel.

Answer (score 2):

It is configured by the host by editing the "Bandwidth Processing Frequency" in their Web Host Manager

See [Schedule Configuration](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/StatsConfig) for further information.

Another document of interest might be: [Apparent Discrepancies in Bandwidth Usage Statistics](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/BandwidthDiscrepancies)  which explains discrepancies in statistics between certain log analysis programs in CPAnel.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so please award points and mark it as answered.